# Unable to invoke Meteor.call from Client in MeteorJS?

Tags: meteor

Using meteor 0.5.7 - following the Parties example - made client, server folders, and placed respective client.js and server.js files in them. I have autopublish, insecure removed, and added email package. I can't get the Meteor.call to fire off, debugging shows that it gets bypassed, I'm loosely following this - http://goo.gl/MV26m - and I still don't understand.

```
// server.js
Meteor.startup(function () {
  process.env.MAIL_URL = '...'; // using mailgun URL
});

Meteor.methods({
   call_me: function (options) {
     var options = options || {};
     Email.send({
      from: options.from,
      to: options.to,
      replyTo: options.from || undefined,
      subject: options.subj,
      text: options.msg,
     });
   },
});

// client.js
Template.form.events({
 'click .submit' : function (event, template) {
   var from = template.find("#from").value;
   var to = template.find("#to").value;
   var subj = template.find("#subj").value;
   var msg = template.find("#msg").value;
   var options = { from: from, to: to, subj: subj, msg:msg };

   Meteor.call('call_me', options, function(err, data) {
    if (err)
     console.log(err);
   });
 }
});

// client.html - the gist of it
<body>
  {{> page }}
</body>
<template name="page">
  {{> form }}
</template>
<template name="form">
  <form ....
</template>
```

Lastly, I actually had the Meteor.methods({...}); sitting in a model.js file outside the client/server folders - and it still didn't fire off emails, or invoke the Meteor.call method. I'm kinda trying to wrap my head around the notion of a stub in the aforementioned attached link, wrapped the call within a function and called it, and I still didn't get any activity. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Are you developing on `localhost`? If so, `Email.send` won't send an email, it will print the email to your console (eg. terminal)

Comment: I am developing on localhost, but email doesnt print to console (term/web) - I placed debugger; within the Meteor.call function, and it didn't even call it. Hrm, Chrome inspect didn't provide an error, but Firefox did - "[17:30:25.585] POST http://localhost:3000/sockjs/566/hkevinpk/xhr_send [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]" - not sure what it means just yet, but perhaps a clue that I'll research further.

Comment: Your Meteor call and Meteor.methods look right. Please post a gist on github with the actual files, and we'll be able to better assist.

Comment: Here's my gist, ignore the extra stuff in packages - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5053919. I now get [22:11:53.834] Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR @ http://localhost:3000/packages/stream/sockjs-0.3.4.js?c752466d04291fd7580e8f38f4233193c0eb069e:1054 - still running on localhost.

Comment: Tried these locally - examples worked out the box - http://blog.mailgun.net/post/41958103075/create-a-web-app-from-scratch-in-under-5-minutes-with, http://blog.mailgun.net/post/41324647061/native-mailgun-integration-lets-meteor-apps-send-email

Comment: Try taking out the `<form>` tag and commenting `Process.env.MAIL_URL`. It worked for me. `<form>` is probably being handled by browser and not by your event.

Comment: Prashant, that did it - works now. I don't have a way to set as answer, unless you do and I'll check it.

Comment: I posted this as answer. I am trying to figure out what the problem could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried your gist. Removing the `<form>` tag and commenting out `Process.env.MAIL_URL` did it. The `<form>` tag is blocking the event trigger to button click.